# Android: How to avoid callback hell in retrofit2 enqueue function?

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, retrofit2, coroutine

I am a beginner Android developer.
I've had similar callback hells before, but I'm confused as even Googling doesn't tell me exactly how to avoid callback hells in these case.

```
fun requestGetProduct(id: Long) {
        repository.getProduct(id).enqueue(
            object : Callback<ProductEntity> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ProductEntity>,
                    response: Response<ProductEntity>
                ) {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        _title.postValue(response.body()?.title)
                        _price.postValue(
                            "${DecimalFormat("###,###").format(response.body()?.price)} 円"
                        )
                        _description.postValue(response.body()?.description)

                        if (response.body()?.imagePath != null) {
                            repository.getProductImage(
                                id,
                                response.body()!!.imagePath!!
                            ).enqueue(
                                object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
                                    override fun onResponse(
                                        call: Call<ResponseBody>,
                                        response: Response<ResponseBody>
                                    ) {
                                        if (response.code() == 200)
                                            _imageByteArray.postValue(
                                                response.body()?.bytes()
                                            )

                                    }

                                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                                        Log.e("サーバーエラー:", t.stackTraceToString())
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProductEntity>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("サーバーエラー:", t.stackTraceToString())
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

In the case of retrofit's callback function, I write something in the current scope with onResponse, how can I make `getProductImage()` know that the response from `getProduct()` was successful in onResponse?

Often people tell me to use RxJava or Coroutine, but I want to use Coroutine. It would be helpful if you could tell me exactly how to use Coroutine to avoid callback hell in Retrofit.
I think it will be easier to understand by looking at the code than by hearing the explanation.

It was long talk, but in conclusion,

1. **when getProduct() is successfully completed using a coroutine for
   easy readability,**
2. **I want to write it so that it looks like sequential code so that getProductImage() is executed.**

Comment: check out this link for usage of Rxjava and coroutine instend callback mechanism,It might be help full. https://www.lukaslechner.com/comparing-kotlin-coroutines-with-callbacks-and-rxjava/

Comment: @MaulikTogadiya 
thank you. In order to implement this, should the return object of each function of the API service class be something instead of Call<Something> and add 'suspend' before 'fun OOO'?

Comment: Use `suspend` but don’t return Call. Just return the thing Call would have wrapped if you weren’t using `suspend`. When you call the function, use try/catch. The catch block takes the place of `onFailure`. But you can wrap a series of calls in try with only one catch.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you ! When I want to see api's response code, Can I change return type SomethingResponseEntity to Response<SomethingResponseEntity> if I want to know the response code or errorbody too?

Comment: It's better to split your post to two separate posts.
One for the 'response' question.
And the other for the coroutines implementation.

Comment: @Mahmoud I think the comments on this post have given people like me the answer they want, so I think it will be helpful for people like me who didn't know about retrofit2 and async even if I leave it as is :)